# Navigating Through Data in a List in C#

Tags: c#, crud

I have a project I am creating where I am able to perform CRUD actions on Jobs and Tasks in C#. As part of this, I want to retrieve all jobs from my database with a completed status of 'completed'.

The code I have created so far is:

```
 private void RefreshData(int recordIndex)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdvancedProgramming;Integrated Security=True";
        List<CompletedJob> completedJobs = new List<CompletedJob>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT job.Description, job.Price, ass.Name AS AssignedTo, comp.Name AS Completed, cust.Name AS CustomerName FROM dbo.Jobs job, dbo.Customers cust, dbo.AssignedToes ass, dbo.Completeds comp WHERE comp.Name = 'Complete' AND comp.Id = job.Completed";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string jobDescription = reader.GetString(0);
                        decimal jobPrice = reader.GetDecimal(1);
                        string assignedTo = reader.GetString(2);
                        string jobStatus = reader.GetString(3);
                        string customerName = reader.GetString(4);
                        currentRecord = recordIndex;
                        // Create a new Job object using the retrieved data
                        CompletedJob compJob = new CompletedJob(customerName, jobDescription, jobPrice, assignedTo, jobStatus);

                        // Add the Job object to a list of completed jobs
                        completedJobs.Add(compJob);

                        cmbCustomer.Items.Add(customerName).ToString();
                        cmbCustomer.SelectedValue = customerName.ToString();
                        txtDescription.Text = jobDescription;
                        txtPrice.Text = jobPrice.ToString();
                        cmbAssignedTo.Items.Add(assignedTo).ToString();
                        cmbAssignedTo.SelectedValue = assignedTo.ToString();
                        cmbCompleted.Items.Add(jobStatus).ToString();
                        cmbCompleted.SelectedValue = jobStatus.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

So far, this displays one record from my database with a completed status of 'completed'. I know the SQL query works fine as this has been tested in my database and shows all my results.

I want to be able to navigate through these results using 2 buttons for PreviousRecord and NextRecord.

My code for these 2 buttons is below:

```
private void PreviousRecord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentRecord > 0)
        {
            currentRecord--;
            RefreshData(currentRecord);
        }
    }

    private void NextRecord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentRecord < cmbCompleted.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            currentRecord++;
            RefreshData(currentRecord);
        }
    }
```

At the top of my code, I am calling the RefreshData method with an index of 0. And setting a variable for currentRecord and making this equal 0.

```
RefreshData(0);    
int currentRecord = 0;
```

Does anyone know why my NextRecord and PreviousRecord buttons are not displaying the next and previous record when I am clicking them? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The SQL query will always return all records which eventually can give you a memory problem, specially with a reader storing all the results until you find the one you are interested in. - Why not use the paging concept to only return the records you are interested in? Using `ORDERBY`, `OFFSET` and `FETCH` you can query only the data you want to begin with.

Comment: How sure are you that the if () conditions are resolving to true in your PreviousRecord / NextRecord methods?

Comment: I think the `while` should be done something like this: `var tmpIndex = 0; while (reader.Read() && tmpIndex++ != currentIndex)` to keep track of where the reader is reading and stop at the right moment. Besides that, this is a very inefficient way of reading through unneeded data... Also, your query does not have an ORDER BY which means that the next result may be sorted differently / randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to be more sophisticated and have a better separation of concerns. I am assuming you are using Windows Forms. Much of Windows Forms relies on the underlying business objects informing the UI that a value of a property has changed, and the UI needs to rebind.

In this instance if you wish to scroll through a list of records you may want to have a class to represent your list of jobs; and expose the current record through a property on that class, and ensure your `CompletedJobList` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

e.g.:

```
public class CompletedJobList : IEnumerable<CompletedJob>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<CompletedJob> _items = new List<CompletedJob>();
    private NotifyPropertyChangedHandler _notifyPropertyChanged;
    private int _currentIndex = -1;

    public event NotifyPropertyChangedHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { this._notifyPropertyChanged = (NotifyPropertyChangedHandler)Delegate.Combine(this._notifyPropertyChanged, value); }
        remove { this._notifyPropertyChanged = (NotifyPropertyChangedHandler)Delegate.Remove(this._notifyPropertyChanged, value); }
    }

    public bool CanIncrement => this._items.Count > 0 && this._currentIndex < this._items.Count -1;

    public bool CanDecrement => this._currentIndex > 0;

    public CompletedJob CurrentItem => this._currentIndex == -1 ? null : this._items[this._currentIndex]; 

    public void Increment()
    {
        if(!this.CanIncrement)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Cannot increment list");
        }
        this.ChangeIndex(1);
    }

    public void Decrement()
    {
        if(!this.CanDecrement)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Cannot decrement");
        }
        this.ChangeIndex(-1);
    }

    private void ChangeIndex(int amount)
    {
        this._currentIndex += amount;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        // better if this object was created via a repository. But at the least encapsulate the data access.
        // connection, command etc...
        using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            this._items.Add(new CompletedJob(
                reader.GetString(0),
                reader.GetDecimal(1),
                reader.GetString(2),
                reader.GetString(3),
                reader.GetString(4)));
        }

        if(this._items.Count > 0) 
        {
            this._currentIndex = 0;
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable<CompletedJob>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._items.GetEnumerator();
    } 

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(this._notifyPropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this._notifyPropertyChanged.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your WindowsForm you will need to set up two BindingSources - both with as an Object. One BindingSource will need to be setup with the `typeof(CompletedJobList)` so you can bind the enabled property to `CanIncrement` and `CanDecrement` respectively. The other BindingSource will need to be set up with the `typeof(CompletedJob)` and to bind the controls that will display the details of the CompletedJob to that of the BindingSource. And finally - to set up the Binding of the second BindingSource's DataSource property to that of CompletedJobList::CurrentItem property.

This way - you initially will display nothing because CompletedJobList::CurrentItem is null. Assuming one can click on the "Increment" button - it's handler will call CompletedJobList::Increment(). Internally this will cause a NotifyPropertyChanged event to fire - telling the BindingSource that its DataSource property has changed and needs to be refreshed. It will do so - and because that will now have a valid reference, the controls whose job it is to display the details of that CompletedJob should now do so without trouble.

This is a very cursory explanation of Windows Forms databinding and I haven't done it in a while - but essentially you do not want to manually be setting the values of these controls. Instead you should use Databinding to map between a control's UI property e.g.: `Textbox::Text` and an object's property e.g.: `CompletedJob::Description`. In this manner most of the ugly event handling code can go away, and you need to worry only about instantiating your datasources, setting up the datasource of the BindingSources, and then any "actions" like button click handlers which need to call methods on your models. The code will be much cleaner and reliable because of it.